# Drupal 7 Index pdf files in search

Tags: drupal, search, pdf, indexing

Does anyone know of a way to include pdf documents in the search for drupal 7?

I can't find anything to achieve this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [drupal indexing of uploaded documents (pdf, word, etc)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184159/drupal-indexing-of-uploaded-documents-pdf-word-etc)

Answer (score 4):

The [Apache Solr Attachments](http://drupal.org/project/apachesolr_attachments) module does this, but currently only has a development (not stable) release for Drupal 7.

Answer (score 4):

Check out the [Search API module](http://drupal.org/project/search_api) and it's sibling module [Search API Attachments](http://drupal.org/project/search_api_attachments). It uses [Apache Tika](http://tika.apache.org/) to parse text from documents.

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

https://drupal.org/project/search_files

This is slightly lighter weight but given SOLR's power and community adoption it is probably still the best return for effort (as a service or installed yourself), whether using [Apache SOLR modules](https://drupal.org/project/apachesolr) or [Search API](https://drupal.org/project/search_api_solr) modules.