# Drupal 7 Search files: does not index the name of the files

Tags: file, search, pdf, drupal, indexing

I have installed Search Files with PDF capabilities in Drupal 7.2

When it contains text, this functionality correctly indexes the contents of the PDF files.

However, it does not index the name of the file itself.

For example : NEW_ADDED_FILE_12345.pdf

I would like the engine to index the content of the file, BUT ALSO :

NEW, ADDED, FILE, 12345

Comment: possible duplicate of [Drupal 7 Index pdf files in search](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5960555/drupal-7-index-pdf-files-in-search)

Answer (score 0):

By default Drupal indexes attachment titles (eg the text of the link to file). In order to index the file names you can use the [Search API](https://drupal.org/project/search_api) module and it's sibling modules like the [Search API Attachments](https://drupal.org/project/search_api_attachments).

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I have checked that Drupal indexes the names of attachments.

However, the aim is to index the name of numerous files that are not attachments but simply present in a directory.

Comment: You should have mentioned that before. If Drupal does not connect files with its database then it will not work anyway. So in this case you have to connect them somehow to the database, maybe through the [file_entity](https://drupal.org/project/file_entity) and [media](https://drupal.org/project/media) module that support bulk file uploading through a directory.